# Python - How do you import downloaded directories/modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, installation, python-import

This is the first time I have attempted to use anything other than what's provided by python.

I have recently gotten into pythons provided Tkinter, though due to some issues I decided to use another GUI, and heard that PyQt was highly recommended, so I downloaded that and looked into various tutorials. In these tutorials, I cannot seem to execute any of the import statements in said tutorials that relate to PyQt, primarily PyQt5 (I have checked I have the correct version number by the way).

So for instance:

```
import PyQt5
```

raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/MEBO/PycharmProjects/Music/testing.py", line 1, in <module>
       import Qt
ImportError: No module named 'Qt'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I have a lot of research into this. I've heard people talk of using pip to install modules, and I have done this be safe (as well as downloading it from the internet), I've tried changing the project interpreter to versions Python3/ 2.7/ 2.6, appending the path name to the sys.path directory, (which I really know nothing about to be honest, I was hoping I'd get lucky), though nothing seems to work.

Are you supposed to be able to just import a module off the bat, or do you have to set some things up first?

Comment: Hve you tried installing SIP firstly? ([this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html))

Comment: Yes, Erm, well no, I just read up on it in the 'README' section of the installation folder, i've just downloaded it now :)

Though I must add that I really have no clue on what's going on, am just trying to follow the instructions. Also I only knew that I had to read 'readme' through pot luck by going through the python docs

Comment: If you have no clue what to do, *always* read README, it helps a lot with everything.

Comment: which module in PyQt5 you wanted?

Comment: Hey Fahad, not really sure, the plan was to get a foothold by importing what was ever imported in the tutorials, and then taking it from there.

Answer (score 1):

For windows download the package and extract it to **(path where python installed)\Python27\Lib** and then try to import.

Answer (score 0):

**Specific to PyQt**

This package cannot just be downloaded and imported, it must be built because it is not pure python, it uses Qt (C++) and requires dependancies. Read this [tutorial](http://movingthelamppost.com/blog/html/2013/07/12/installing_pyqt____because_it_s_too_good_for_pip_or_easy_install_.html) on installation.

There is also a very complete python package distribution, [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), that includes [pyqt and much more](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html).  Almost all the packages I ever looked at are in there.

**In general to pure python code**

In other cases, if you place modules/code that has been download into the directory that your python script is run from, you can import off the bat, or you can append/insert any folder to the `sys.path`.

```
# importer will search here last
sys.path.append('/path/to/code/')

# importer will search here second, right after script's directory
# this can be useful to override a module temporarily...
sys.path.insert(1,'/path/to/code/')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall read into the documentation you provided, and extract all that I can! I'll also look into the techniques you mentioned. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @JimJam I highly recommend the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) package distribution.  If you like python so far with just the core features, you are going to **love** all the other packages out there, and this provides a simple installer that handles getting all the major ones up an running very easily.